# Excel vba - Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. error

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, vb6

I am new to excel VBA and in this project I want if the cell B4 is NOT empty and the cell C4 is empty then C4 should be highlighted. Likewise the code should loop up to B16 cell. "AMA79" is the sheetname. I am getting Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. error using this code. Can you please let me know what should be done to correct this.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B4:B16")

For i = 4 To 16
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AMA79")
If Range(B, i).Value <> "" And Range(D, i).Value = "" Then
Range(c, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
End With
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
**Edit:**

```
   Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("AMA79")

For i = 4 To 16

If ws.Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And ws.Range("D" & i).Value = "" Then

ws.Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
ws.Range("B29").Value = "Please validate the cells highlighted"

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Also can you let me know if I can show a message on a cell using this `Range("$B$29").Value = "My desired message"` if any of the columns get highlighted?

Comment: I did not really get it. You want to make appear a message in this `Range("B29")` if one of the cells in column C is highlithed?

Comment: correct! Its like if any of the cells are highlighted with above code, then B29 should show the message "Please validate the cells highlighted."